# How to use NHibernate in a layered architecture

Tags: nhibernate

I've seen many similar questions about NHibernate session management (so I know I'm not alone) but no answers that address abstracting the details of session management from other layers.

In simple terms, I have a Domain layer that has objects like Customer, Product, and Order.  I have an Integration layer that that defines services for the application like IOrderEntryService containing methods like Get<Product>(int id) or Get<Customer>(int id) and Get<Order>(int id).  I have a business rules layer that uses these services to get Customers, Orders, etc.  Business rules use only the service interfaces to avoid hard dependencies on any specific service implementation.

I can implement IOrderEntryService with NHibernate and define mappings to support properties like Customer.Orders as well as Order.Customer and similar associations using lazy loading.  In my implementation of Get<Customer>(int id) I open an ISession object, obtain a Customer and then dispose my ISession.  Later, if I reference Customer.Orders, I receive an exception, because there is no current session.  I understand the reasons for this, but I'm having difficulty finding a workaround that doesn't bind higher layers to NHibernate.  All the examples I've found suggest methods for obtaining an NHibernate.ISession per request so that the session remains open during the full request lifetime.  I struggle with this, because this binds higher layers to the NHibernate ISession object.

Is there an abstract way to manage "sessions" that does not bind higher layers to NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a framework that is able to manage transactions in a "implicit way" as Spring.Net.

It will manage the sessions making "open", "close", "commit" or "rollback" "ISession's"/"Transactions."

**About your question**: I think there is no way to keep the session open (during presentation rendering) without doing part of the management over the ISession on the higher layers.

There is no problem in keeping management over ISession on the higher layers, provided the [management over ITransaction] is kept out of them.

With "Spring.Net" you can do a 'management over ITransaction' on your favorite layer using: `[Transaction]` and `[Transaction(ReadOnly = true)]`.

Comment: Managing transactions is not a problem since, generally, my updates are contained within a single update ( Update<Customer>, Insert<Order>, etc)  My problem is managing a "session" at a higher layer.  It makes sense that I need to obtain some sort of IDisposable object and retain this only as long as needed in my higher layer.  I would prefer that be something that is not directly dependent on NHibernate.  This way, if my implementation needs to change, or needs to use additional services that may not also be implemented in NHibernate, I will be able to do so without breaking the client..

Comment: @user734929 it is not only about transactions. Spring handles automatically the Sessions when you have a method [Transaction]. So if you want, for example to annotate a controller method (don't know if you are using MVC) you can. Actually I do not recommend to do that, but if you do, all subsequent calls on dao will be "nested" on that first Transaction/Session. The point I recommend is inside a service layer that is supposed to do some atomic actions on your model objects, like persisting a order, for example. It is worth to remind you that Spring does not  depend on NHibernate.

Comment: Spring.NET works extremely well with NHibernate. I think the download comes with an example called 'Northwind' which shows what you need (though I may be wrong). You will end up with a really neat layered application (DAO, Service, Controller) and can take advantage of the Transactional unit tests that Spring.NET lets you do too, which is a really powerful feature i.e. the tests actually write to a real DB and then rollback the transaction at the end of the test so your DB is clean again. It's as easy as defining a transaction manager and then using the attributes as Hailton says.

Comment: Plus Spring.NET 2 is on the verge of being released. Not sure what's new yet but looking forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Sharp architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) and sharp [architecture lite](https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite) projects. Both of them give solid understanding on how to use nhibernate in web based systems. Even more they provide you a background on other approaches like IoC containers, DDD, TDD and so on.

Comment: Highly recommend Sharp architecture as a starting point into using nHibernate and Castle. Even if you do not end up using it, you will gain a valuable insight into how many people do the sort of architecture you are describing.